# Pandas - Add mean, max, min as row in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Dataframe evntually converts to Excel...
Trying to create a additional row with the avg and max above each column.

- Do not want to disturb the original headers for the actual data.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCqPg.png)

I dont want to hard-code column names as these will change need kind of abstract. I attempted to create a max but failed. I need the max above the column headers.

Comment: DataFrame is only to work with table which has columns and rows. It is NOT to creae extra information above table. If you want to create Excel file then you may have to use modules created to work exactly with Excel data.

Comment: If I wanted something like this, I would create a separate _statistics_ dataframe with the same columns as your original dataframe, and rows indexed as `avg` and `max`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I don't know how to create above the dataframe, but I believe that in the end it might be a good solution:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = {
    'date and time':['2022-03-01', '2022-03-02', '2022-03-03', '2022-03-04'],
    '<PowerAC--->':[40, 20, 9, 12]
              }
df = pd.DataFrame(df)

cols = ['<PowerAC--->']
agg = (df[cols].agg(['mean', max]))

out = pd.concat([df, agg])

print(out)
```

Answer (score 0):

A one-liner method which also remove the "NaN" values to make it visually better (I'm a bit OCD ;))

```
df.append(df.agg({'<PowerAC--->' : ['mean', max]})).fillna('')
```

Comment: ok i c but this hardcodes PowerAC which is not always a column lol

Comment: Not sure to understand what you mean. Giving your example, it works. We can't guess the missing information if you don't tell us ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would say it's a good idea to keep your data separated from the reporting on it - I don't really see the logic for an "additional row above the column".

I would generate statistics for the overall data as a separate dataframe.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1)
t = pd.date_range(start='2022-05-31', end='2022-06-07')
x = np.random.rand(len(t))

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': t, 'data': x})
print(df)

# The 'numeric_only=False' behaviour will become default in a future version of pandas
d_mean = df.mean(numeric_only=False)
d_max = df.max()
# We need to transpose this, as the `d_mean` and `d_max` are Series (columns), and we want them as rows
df_stats = pd.DataFrame({'mean': d_mean, 'max':d_max}).transpose()
print(df_stats)
```

`df` output:

```
        date      data
0 2022-05-31  0.417022
1 2022-06-01  0.720324
2 2022-06-02  0.000114
3 2022-06-03  0.302333
4 2022-06-04  0.146756
5 2022-06-05  0.092339
6 2022-06-06  0.186260
7 2022-06-07  0.345561
```

`df_stats` output:

```
                    date      data
mean 2022-06-03 12:00:00  0.276339
max  2022-06-07 00:00:00  0.720324
```

You could add this and the dataframe together with

```py
pd.concat([df_stats, df])
```

which looks like

```
                    date      data
mean 2022-06-03 12:00:00  0.276339
max  2022-06-07 00:00:00  0.720324
0    2022-05-31 00:00:00  0.417022
1    2022-06-01 00:00:00  0.720324
2    2022-06-02 00:00:00  0.000114
3    2022-06-03 00:00:00  0.302333
4    2022-06-04 00:00:00  0.146756
5    2022-06-05 00:00:00  0.092339
6    2022-06-06 00:00:00   0.18626
7    2022-06-07 00:00:00  0.345561
```

but I would keep them separate unless you've got a very good reason to.

There may be some way which makes sense using a multi-index, but that's a bit beyond me, and probably beyond the scope of this question.

Edit: If you don't infer any meaning from the max and mean of the date column but still want something compatiable with that column (i.e. still a `datetime` but effectively null) you could replace it by `np.datetime64['NaT']` (NaT similar to NaN, but "not a time"):

```py
df_stats['date'] = np.datetime64['NaT']
print(pd.concat([df_stats, df]).head())
```

output:

```
           date      data
mean        NaT  0.276339
max         NaT  0.720324
0    2022-05-31  0.417022
1    2022-06-01  0.720324
2    2022-06-02  0.000114
```

Comment: ahh ic , so rsn why I want to combine the df stats and df is bc i want them both one excel file only

Comment: @AnirudhGattu the `pd.concat` command will do that, but I'd do it as the last thing before exporting to excel, and not use it to e.g. overwrite your dataframe.